# Golang nanny process starting child process

Tags: io, go, child-process

The idea here is that my executable can be started normally (in which case it runs my business logic), or it can be wrapped in a nanny process (which starts a child process to run the business logic, and if the child process dies restarts it indefinitely).  Here are some more specific requirements:

- As invisible to the caller as possible
- STDOUT/STDERR of the child should appear to be coming from the parent (so that if I run it in a terminal, it's invisible what's happening)
- A dead child is restarted
- A dead parent kills the child (so that ctrl-C in a terminal is sane)

Here is what I have (working).  Is there a cleaner way, or am I wasting resources somehow?

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "flag"
    "time"
)

var nanny string
var myparent int 

func init() {
    flag.StringVar(&nanny, "nanny", "", "execute 'run -nanny run' to run in nanny mode.")
    flag.IntVar(&myparent, "myparent", 0, "never run 'run -myparent xxx'; it is used by nanny mode.")
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    if nanny != "" {
        nannymain()
    } else {
        realmain()
    }   
}

func realmain() {
    if myparent != 0 { 
        go nannywatcher()
    }   

    // ... run arbitrary business logic ...
}

func nannywatcher() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
        if os.Getppid() != myparent {
            // We've been reparented!  If our nanny was killed someone is
            // trying to kill us, and the nanny will take care of the logging.
            // Just die.
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }
}

func nannymain() {
    pid := os.Getpid()
    for {
        cmd := exec.Command(nanny, fmt.Sprintf("-myparent=%d", pid))
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
        cmd.Run()
        // The child died.  We will restart him.
    }
}
```

Comment: Do those *have* to be separate processes, or is it just the solution you thought of to achieve the other requirements (some business logic that outputs on STDOUT/STDERR, and a flag that executes the business logic and restarts it whenever it dies)? I can think of a cleaner & more idiomatic way to do that, but this uses goroutines instead of processes.